# InDesign: How to place multiple images in a text frame

Tags: adobe-indesign, images

I need to place many images into a single text frame. I know that you can `place` as many images at a time as you like, but I can't figure out a way to place them **inside** a `text frame`. The only way I can put images in the text frame is one-at-a-time by placing an image outside the text frame and cut-pasting one-by-one into the text frame.

There's got to be a faster way to do this, right ?

**EDIT**: What I'm trying to accomplish: I'm making a book which contains mostly images, on some pages there are a few images on some only one. I need the to flow automatically in case I need to add or remove images later on.

Answer (score 2):

You are not pasting into a text frame, you are pasting into a text *flow*.

The only way to tell inDesign where in this flow you want the image(s) is to place the cursor and paste.

If you want all the objects in a single place, **group them before copying**.

If you are trying to incorporate [runaround](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaround_%28typography%29), then don't do it this way, place images beside the text and use "text wrap."

If you are, say, making custom bullets (etc), I can say from experience that you should look into using a custom font editor to get your shape into a font format, otherwise you will be manually adjusting 100s of tiny images (or better, scripting it if you are so inclined).

Comment: I'm making a book which contains mostly images, on some pages there are a few images on some only one. I need the to flow automatically in case I need to add or remove images later on. So that's what I'm trying to do, maybe there's some better way ?

Answer (score 0):

Import the images using XML? Just create a basic XML file which references the graphics in question.

Alternately, get the filenames into the text flow and use a script which will replace the filenames w/ the matching graphics.

Comment: That's is an interesting solution. Can you refer any scripts you are familiar with?